# Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datepicker

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker.
But it's not working. Can someone please assist me in fixing this?

I have searched stack overflow but nothing useful found yet..

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>BootStrap Practice </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/moment.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Owes Shubho</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class='well'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>$(function() {

  $( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });

});</script>
      
      
      
      
      <footer>
          <p class="text-center">&copy; Owes Shubho 2015</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/moment.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `moment.js` added twice, once in header and then in footer, check your browser console log for errors and what is `$( document ).ajaxStop( function()`

Comment: **Thanks bro** i was change id and it's works now.